# How to view a .ssf file (cctv video footage) on a Mac

Tags: macos, video-player

Ive searched everywhere online and cant seem to find a video player for mac that supports .ssf files. I've tried Itunes and VLC but nothing.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Flagged for closure as Off-Topic. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, while this question is about general computer usage. You may get more help over at SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a program that could read ssf files. I know your post is several months old, but it did show as a Google search results, so I thought I would share the application that I found for the benefit of other folks who might see your original post.

I have placed an ssf player on my google drive, so others can download it.  It came with my DVR card.  The file name is SSF_STL_Stream_Format_CCTV_camera_video_player.zip. The download [link](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0DonYAabkWAU0tPUlhzMEtLa1E&export=download)

Comment: ive been looking for weeks for a solution to opening ssf files, and trying to download players. you rock!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Check the file headers in a text editor (like notepad) to see if you can work out what type of encoding it uses.  Most of the CCTV PVR manufacturers have their own player software so see if you can work out which type it came from and if there is an associated player.

VLC will play most any type of encoding but these CCTV types are often optimised for quality/file size and may use custom types.  You can manually select the type of encoding when you try to open a file in VLC but it normally does a fair guess by itself.

Best of luck!

Comment: this is what the top line says `STL Stream Format v1.0ˇˇ¿ÒˇT›`, the rest is just gibberish, variation of characters.